# Show element in "hover" state "on" when other elements not hovered

Tags: css, hover

I have several divs that should be enlarged on hover, and am using this code to achieve that:

```
.classname:hover {
  transform:scaleY(1.1);
  transform-origin: bottom; }
```

I want one of the divs to show enlarged **except** when any of the other divs are being hovered.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieving using jQuery:

After creating .hover class and adding it to the first div, you could use this jQuery function:

```
$('.classname').hover(
       function(){ $('.hover').removeClass('hover'); $(this).addClass('hover') },
       function(){ $('.classname:first-child').addClass('hover'); $(this).removeClass('hover') }
)
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/dragosmicu/pen/vxeNze

Answer (score 0):

```css
.classname{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#454545;
margin:20px;

}
.classname:hover {
  transform:scaleY(1.1);
  transform-origin: bottom; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="classname"></div>
<div class="classname"></div>
<div class="classname"></div>
<div class="classname"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks -- that is what I have now, but I want the first div to show enlarged EXCEPT when one of the other 3 are hovered

Comment: Yup its possible with jquery I am looking for a pure css solution.Please edit above post if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use some Jquery.

Have you tried something with an if function and .css("transform", "scaleY(1.0)"; applied to your div when others are on hover? You will need to add another class to the first div and make it by default enlarged then when the mouse hover one of your other classe it will reduce.

Is that what you are looking for?